# Installing packages from the command line with Composer is not working

Tags: composer-php, zsh

I tried using Composer to install phpcs globally. That did not work so I tried using it to install Laravel. That did not work either.

```
~ ❯❯❯ composer global require "squizlabs/php_codesniffer=*"
Changed current directory to /Users/joe/.composer
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files

~ ❯❯❯ rehash

~ ❯❯❯ which phpcs
phpcs not found

~ ❯❯❯ echo $path
/usr/local/heroku/bin /usr/local/bin /usr/bin /bin /usr/sbin /sbin /opt/X11/bin /usr/local/sbin
~/.composer/vendor/bin/ /usr/local/bin/node
```

~/.composer/vendor/bin/ is in my path.  I am unsure what to do to fix this.  I am using zshell on OSX 10.11.1

Comment: I tried the proposed solutions but they aren't working for me.  I am going to try installing it with PEAR.

Comment: What makes you think that the installation itself didn't run properly?

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution :

- Installing globally PHPCS

```
composer global require squizlabs/php_codesniffer
```

- Know yout $path

```
echo $PATH
```

- Add line below into your `~/.zshrc` ou `~/.bashrc`

```
export PATH="/home/$USER/.config/composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"
```

More info  [here](https://gist.github.com/vinnyfs89/b2cabaf1b8b81f602b18fe5f6f5dd04d)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i could reproduce your issue:

`composer global require "squizlabs/php_codesniffer=*"` isn't installing anything.

Thats strange, because the command without `global` works:

`composer require "squizlabs/php_codesniffer=*"`. It installs 2.3.4 into the local project.

---

My suggestion is to simply drop the wildcard operator `*` and specify a version.

Like so `composer global require squizlabs/php_codesniffer=^2.3 -vvv --profile`

This installs version 2.3.4 into the global composer folder.

Comment: `composer global require squizlabs/php_codesniffer` without any specific version requirement will work as well - with the added benefit of only installing a version compatible with everything else that is already installed - not necessarily the latest version, if that one is incompatible with anything.